# A C++11 std::map program can't be compiled in clang 3.4

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, clang++

I am new to C++. I tried to compile a very simple std::map progeam in clang 3.4 with "-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++" flags, I got errors that I don't understand.

```
#include<map>
#include<string>

template<typename KeyType>
struct ReverseSort {
    bool operator() (const KeyType& key1, const KeyType& key2) {
        return (key1 > key2);
    }
};

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    map<int, string> mapIntToString1;
    map<int, string, ReverseSort<int> > mapIntToString4(mapIntToString1.cbegin(), mapIntToString1.cend());

    return 0;
}
```

The error is:

```
map:457:17: error: no matching function for call to object of type 'const ReverseSort<int>'
```

I know the error comes from the 3rd line in main(), just don't understand why.
Same program is good in g++ 4.8.2 with "-std=c++11" flag, and I believe it is also good in VC2010.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use `std::greater<int>`?!

Comment: what exactly is **VC2010** ?

Comment: @Jagannath Your comment was way out of line. That was a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `operator()` member must be `const`:

```
bool operator() (const KeyType& key1, const KeyType& key2) const
{   //                                                     ^^^^^
    return (key1 > key2);
}
```

Comment: Note that both GCC 4.9's libstdc++ and MSVS2013 do not "catch" this.

Comment: @rubenvb I don't think it is required by the standard.

Comment: @juanchopanza: if you look at the `value_compare` class in `23.4.4.1` (n3337 p763), its `operator()` is `const`, which makes the `Compare` object `const` in that function's context, and thus a its `operator()` must also be `const`, right? Or am I reading that wrong? Not sure in how far this translates to a requirement though...

Comment: Now I can get it compiled with "const"

Comment: @Stephen: Yes, I'd expect as much. But don't reinvent all those wheels and use `std::greater<int>`!